# boost::python::return_value_policy<bp::reference_existing_object>() is weakref in python?

Tags: c++, python, boost

I've used `boost::python` in the past, but this problem has me stumped. Here's part of the class I'm having issues with:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();

    //Call to check our collider against all entities that have "tag"
    Collider* Collide(const std::string &tag);
};
```

and here is the `boost::python` code:

```
bp::class_< Entity_wrapper >( "Entity", bp::init< >() )    
        .def( 
            "Collide"
            , (::Monocle::Collider * ( ::Monocle::Entity::* )( ::std::string const & ) )( &::Monocle::Entity::Collide )
            , ( bp::arg("tag") ),
            bp::return_value_policy<bp::reference_existing_object>() )
```

In python if I do something like this:

```
collider = entity.Collision("Paddle")
```

`collider` is a weakref to `type`, not a `Collider`. My other functions that return pointers seem to be fine. Is it just the call policy I'm using? What Collide does is call a static function ("Collide") of the Collision class, which in turn returns a Collider* on success and NULL otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated! If you need anymore information, let me know!

Comment: the boost::python code didn't post properly, here it is again:

bp::class_< Entity_wrapper >( "Entity", bp::init< >() )    
        .def( 
            "Collide"
            , (::Monocle::Collider * ( ::Monocle::Entity::* )( ::std::string const & ) )( &::Monocle::Entity::Collide )
            , ( bp::arg("tag") ),
   bp::return_value_policy<bp::reference_existing_object>() )

Comment: Have you already wrapped the `Collider` class? (Based on the code snippet it looks like you're using Py++, but you never know...) And probably the `CircleCollider` and `RectangleCollider` ones as well, if that's the Monocle engine from zaphire on github.